# Installing a new plugin in Eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse

I'm trying to install a jQuery plug in for eclipse from http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jquerywtp   it comes as a .jar file.  I've tried going to help0---> install new software and adding the jar from the "local" and "archive" options it has there but it causes errors and doesn't allow it.  I've been reading online that you are supposed to place these files inside of the plugin or dropins folder inside of eclipse directory. So I've placed both the .jar files and the extracted folder inside of each but I still cannot see that the software was installed correctly. I've checked the help--> about eclipse--> installed software list and it is not showing up there.  How can I install this plug in?

Comment: "but it causes errors" What errors are these ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be no standard Eclipse plugin.
On the homepage of the plugin is an installation guide:

http://www.langtags.com/jquerywtp/?page_id=4

Comment: You're right it looks like several other people are having problems installing this plug in. Thanks for the link though. Do you know of another way of using jQuery with eclipse?